# Solving a first Order ordinary differential equation with only linear terms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following problem is from the book "Introduction to Ordinary Differential Equations" By Sheply L. Ross. It is problem 8 in section 2.4. It can be found on page 67. I believe I have the wrong answer. Where did I go wrong?

Problem:

Solve the following differential equations.
$$ ( 3x - y + 1 ) dx - ( 6x - 2y - 3) dy = 0 $$

Answer:

I am going to use the substitution $z = 3x -y + 1$.
\begin{align*}
\frac{dz}{dx} &= 3 -  \frac{dy}{dx} \\
dz &= 3 \, dx - dy \\
- dy &= dz - 3 dx \\
dy &= 3 dx - dz \\
z \, dx - ( 6x - 2y - 3) \left( 3 dx - dz \right)  = 0 \\
z \, dx - ( 6x - 2y + 2 - 5) \left( 3 dx - dz \right)  = 0 \\
z \, dx - ( 2z - 5) \left( 3 dx - dz \right)  = 0 \\
z \, dx + (-2z + 5)(3 \, dx - dz) &= 0 \\
(z - 6z + 15)\, dx + (2z-5) dz &= 0 \\
dx + \frac{2z-5 }{-5z + 15 } \, dz &= 0 \\
dx - \frac{2z-5 }{5z - 15 } \, dz &= 0 
\end{align*}
Now we need to perform the following integration:
$$ I = \int \frac{2z-5 }{5z - 15 } \, dz $$
To perform this integration, I use the substitution $u = 5z - 15$ which gives me $du = 5 \, dz$.
\begin{align*}
I &= \int \frac{ \left( 2z - 5 \right) \left( \frac{1}{5} \right) } {u} \, du \\
5z &= u + 15 \\
z &= \frac{u+15}{5} \\
I &= \int \frac{ \left( 2 \left( \frac{u+15}{5} \right)  - 5 \right) \left( \frac{1}{5} \right) } {u} \, du \\
I &= \frac{1}{5} \int \frac{\frac{2u+15} {5} -  5} {u} \, du \\
I &= \frac{1}{5} \int \frac{ \frac{2u + 15 - 25} { 5} } { u } \, du \\
I &= \frac{1}{25} \int \frac{ 2u - 10 }{u} \, du \\
I &= \frac{2u}{25} - \frac{10}{25}  \ln{|u|} + C_1 \\
I &= \frac{1}{25} \left( 2( 5z - 15) \right) - \frac{2}{5} \ln{|5z - 15|} + C_1 \\
x &= \frac{1}{25} \left( 2( 5z - 15) \right) - \frac{2}{5} \ln{|5z - 15|} + C_1 \\
5x &= \frac{1}{5} \left( 2( 5z - 15) \right) - 2 \ln{|5z - 15|} + C \text{ with } C = 5C_1 \\
5x &= \frac{1}{5} \left( 2( 5(3x -y + 1) - 15) \right) - 2 \ln{|5(3x -y + 1) - 15|} + C \\
5x &= \frac{1}{5} \left( 2( 15x -5y + 5 - 15) \right) - 2 \ln{|15x - 5y + 5 - 15|} + C \\
5x &= \frac{1}{5} \left( 30x - 10y - 20 \right) - 2 \ln{|15x - 5y - 10|} + C \\
5x &= \left( 6x - 2y - 4 \right) - 2 \ln{|15x - 5y - 10|} + C
\end{align*}

Now, I am going to check the answer by differentiating it.
\begin{align*}
5 &= 6 - 2 \frac{dy}{dx} - 2 \frac{15 - 5 \frac{dy}{dx}}{15x - 5y - 10} \\
-1 &= - 2 \frac{dy}{dx} - 2 \frac{15 - 5 \frac{dy}{dx}}{15x - 5y - 10} \\
1 &=  2 \frac{dy}{dx} + 2 \frac{15 - 5 \frac{dy}{dx}}{15x - 5y - 10} \\
15x - 5y - 10 &=  2 (15x - 5y - 10) \frac{dy}{dx} + 2  (15 - 5 \frac{dy}{dx}) \\
15x - 5y - 10 &=  2 (15x - 5y - 10) \frac{dy}{dx} +  30 - 10 \frac{dy}{dx} \\
15x - 5y - 40 &=  2 (15x - 5y - 10) \frac{dy}{dx} - 10 \frac{dy}{dx} \\
15x - 5y - 40 &= ( 30x - 10y - 20) \frac{dy}{dx} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{15x - 5y - 40}{30x - 10y - 20} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{ 3x - y + 8 } { 6x - 2y - 4 }
\end{align*}
Hence the answer does not check.

Based upon the comment I got from N74 I have updated my answer. I feel I am closer to the correct solution but I am still off.

I am going to use the substitution $z = 3x -y + 1$.
\begin{align*}
\frac{dz}{dx} &= 3 -  \frac{dy}{dx} \\
dz &= 3 \, dx - dy \\
- dy &= dz - 3 dx \\
dy &= 3 dx - dz \\
z \, dx - ( 6x - 2y - 3) \left( 3 dx - dz \right)  = 0 \\
z \, dx - ( 6x - 2y + 2 - 5) \left( 3 dx - dz \right)  = 0 \\
z \, dx - ( 2z - 5) \left( 3 dx - dz \right)  = 0 \\
z \, dx + (-2z + 5)(3 \, dx - dz) &= 0 \\
(z - 6z + 15)\, dx + (2z-5) dz &= 0 \\
dx + \frac{2z-5 }{-5z + 15 } \, dz &= 0 \\
dx - \frac{2z-5 }{5z - 15 } \, dz &= 0 
\end{align*}
Now we need to perform the following integration:
$$ I = \int \frac{2z-5 }{5z - 15 } \, dz $$
To perform this integration, I use the substitution $u = 5z - 15$ which gives me $du = 5 \, dz$.
\begin{align*}
I &= \int \frac{ \left( 2z - 5 \right) \left( \frac{1}{5} \right) } {u} \, du \\
5z &= u + 15 \\
z &= \frac{u+15}{5} \\
I &= \int \frac{ \left( 2 \left( \frac{u+15}{5} \right)  - 5 \right) \left( \frac{1}{5} \right) } {u} \, du \\
I &= \frac{1}{5} \int \frac{\frac{2u+30} {5} -  5} {u} \, du \\
I &= \frac{1}{5} \int \frac{ \frac{2u + 30 - 25} { 5} } { u } \, du \\
I &= \frac{1}{25} \int \frac{ 2u + 5 }{u} \, du \\
I &= \frac{2u}{25} + \frac{5}{25}  \ln{|u|} + C_1 \\
I &= \frac{1}{25} \left( 2( 5z - 15) \right) + \frac{1}{5} \ln{|5z - 15|} + C_1 \\
x &= \frac{1}{25} \left( 2( 5z - 15) \right) + \frac{1}{5} \ln{|5z - 15|} + C_1 \\
5x &= \frac{1}{5} \left( 2( 5z - 15) \right) + \ln{|5z - 15|} + C \text{ with } C = 5C_1 \\
5x &= \frac{1}{5} \left( 2( 5(3x -y + 1) - 15) \right) + \ln{|5(3x -y + 1) - 15|} + C \\
5x &= \frac{1}{5} \left( 2( 15x -5y + 5 - 15) \right) + \ln{|15x - 5y + 5 - 15|} + C \\
5x &= \frac{1}{5} \left( 30x - 10y - 20 \right) + \ln{|15x - 5y - 10|} + C \\
5x &= \left( 6x - 2y - 4 \right) + \ln{|15x - 5y - 10|} + C
\end{align*}

Now, I am going to check the answer by differentiating it.
\begin{align*}
5 &= 6 - 2 \frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{15 - 5 \frac{dy}{dx}}{15x - 5y - 10} \\
-1 &= - 2 \frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{15 - 5 \frac{dy}{dx}}{15x - 5y - 10} \\
%
1 &=  2 \frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{15 - 5 \frac{dy}{dx}}{15x - 5y - 10} \\
15x - 5y - 10 &= 2(15x - 5y - 10) \frac{dy}{dx} - 15 - 5 \frac{dy}{dx} \\
15x - 5y + 5 &= ( 30x - 10y - 20 - 5 ) \frac{dy}{dx} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{ 15x - 5y + 5 } { 30x - 10y - 25 } = \frac{ 3x - y + 1}{ 6x - 2y - 5} \\
(3x - y + 1) \, dx &= ( 6x - 2y - 5 ) \, dy \\
\end{align*}
Hence the answer does not check.

I now believe that my second answer is correct. The check I did above is not right. Here is my updated check of the answer I got.

Now, I am going to check the answer by differentiating it.
\begin{align*}
5 &= 6 - 2 \frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{15 - 5 \frac{dy}{dx}}{15x - 5y - 10} \\
-1 &= - 2 \frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{15 - 5 \frac{dy}{dx}}{15x - 5y - 10} \\
%
1 &=  2 \frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{15 - 5 \frac{dy}{dx}}{15x - 5y - 10} \\
%
15x - 5y - 10 &= 5y - 10 &= 2(15x - 5y - 10)\frac{dy}{dx} + 5 \frac{dy}{dx}- 15 \\
15x - 5y + 5 &= (30x - 10y - 20)\frac{dy}{dx} + 5 + \frac{dy}{dx} \\
3x - y + 1 &= (6x - 2y - 4)\frac{dy}{dx} + 5 \frac{dy}{dx} \\
3x - y + 1 &= (6x - 2y +1 )\frac{dy}{dx} \\
(3x-y+1) dx &= (6x-2y+1) dy
\end{align*}
Hence the answer checks.

Comment: You have an error here: $\int \frac{ \left( 2 \left( \frac{u+15}{5} \right)  - 5 \right) \left( \frac{1}{5} \right) } {u} \, du \neq \frac{1}{5} \int \frac{\frac{2u+15} {5} -  5} {u} \, du $. The $2$ factor must be distributed over the sum giving $\frac{1}{5} \int \frac{\frac{2u+30} {5} -  5} {u} \, du $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative way to solve the ODE. Starting from

$$(3x−y+1)dx−(6x−2y−3)dy=0$$

we can rearrange to

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3x-y+1}{6x-2y-3}$$

then let $w=3x-y$ so that

$$\frac{dw}{dx}=3-\frac{dy}{dx}\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=3-\frac{dw}{dx}$$

where substituting $w$ forms

$$\frac{w+1}{2w-3}=3-\frac{dw}{dx} \implies \frac{dw}{dx}=3-\frac{w+1}{2w-3}$$

which simplifies to

$$\frac{dw}{dx}=\frac{5w-10}{2w-3}$$

or

$$5dx=\frac{2w-3}{w-2}dw$$

which is separable. Integrating both sides and simplifying forms

$$5x=2w+\ln|w-2|+c$$

then since $w= 3x−y$ we have

$$5x= 2(3x−y) + \ln|3x−y−2| +c$$

which reduces to

$$2y=x+ \ln|3x−y−2| +c$$

to find an explicit solution for $y$, we would need to apply the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 1):

With $z:=3x-y-2$, so that $dz=3dx-dy$, the equation becomes

$$ (z + 3) dx - (2z+1)(3dx-dz)= 0 $$
or
$$-5z\,dx+(2z-1)dz=0,$$

which integrates as

$$2z-\log|z|=5x+c.$$

The solution is

$$2(3x-y-2)-\log|3x-y-2|=5x+c.$$

Your solution has an extra factor $2$.

The solution can be made into an explicit form $y=f(x)$, but that requires the use of Lambert's $W$ function.

Answer (score 0):

$$( 3x - y + 1 ) dx - ( 6x - 2y - 3) dy = 0$$

With substitution:
$$
\begin {cases}z=3x-y+1 
\\ z'=3-y' \\
 y'=3-z'
\end{cases}
$$
$$z-(2z-5)(3-z')=0$$
$$(3-z')=\frac z {(2z-5)}$$
$$z'=5\left ( \frac {z-3} {2z-5} \right )$$
We have the same result here:
$$\frac {(2z-5)} {z-3} dz=5dx$$
It's simple to integrate since $2z-5=2z-6+1$:
$$2dz+\frac {dz} {z-3} =5dx$$
$$2z+\ln| {z-3}| =5x+K$$
Unsubstitute $z=3x-y+1 :$
$$x-2y+\ln| {3x-y-2}| =K$$